# Разделить ячейку на две отдельные ячейки ios

Tags: ios, swift

Нужно разделить ячейку на две части, чтобы при нажатии на одну часть происходило одно действие (на скрине - first action), а на другую часть - другое действие (на скрине - second action). Привожу пример: как в яндекс.почте, когда нажимаешь на область с иконкой письма, то на иконку накладывается чекбокс, и таким образом можно выбрать несколько писем. А если нажать на вторую часть ячейки (в которой краткий текст письма), то произойдет уже другое действие, а именно открытие письма. Во вложении к посту есть скрин с примером. Собственно, сам вопрос: как это сделать? Какие классы, методы нужно использовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи вам необходимо:

1. Создать 2 `UIView` (положить на них все то требуется отображать)
2. Установить для каждого из `UIView` проперти
   `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` для того чтобы можно было
   обрабатывать жесты
3. На каждый из `UIView` повесить свой `UIGestureRecognizer` типа `tap`